send form with button from another component using usecontext in react js
I'm trying to send this form inputs from component A using a button in component B. Both of them are stored in context provider I've created:
context.jsx:
export const SubmitContext = createContext(null);

export const SubmitContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [submitForm, setSubmitForm] = useState((data) => {   
    console.log('Form submitted:', data);
  });

  return (
    <SubmitContext.Provider value={submitForm}>
      {children}
    </SubmitContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SubmitContext;

ComponentA.jsx:
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import SubmitContext from './ContextTest';

const ComponentA = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, register, control, errors } = useForm();
  const submit = useContext(SubmitContext);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    submit    
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller 
        control={control} 
        name="name"
        defaultValue=""
        render={({field}) => (
          <input
            type='text'
            { ...field }
           />
        )}
      />
      <Controller
        name="email"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({ field }) => (
          <input type="email" { ...field } />
        )}
      />      
      <button type="submit">Submit from ComponentA</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ComponentA;

ComponentB.jsx:
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import SubmitContext from './ContextTest';

const ComponentB = () => {
  const submit = useContext(SubmitContext);
  
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    submit 
    console.log('submitted');       
  };
  
  return (
    <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Submit from ComponentB</button>
  );
};
  
export default ComponentB;

and my App.jsx file
import ComponentA from "./ComponentA"
import ComponentB from "./ComponentB"
import { SubmitContextProvider } from "./ContextTest"

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <SubmitContextProvider>
        <div>
          <ComponentA />
          <ComponentB />
        </div>
      </SubmitContextProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

Here what I've done until now. So what going wrong that make Button not working?
I'm trying to create a second button that send between component A and component B which are not parent or children and are used with useContext hook.

Can you share the code you have in your context? That would be helpful in figuring out what you're not doing right.

The first file Context.js has all what you're asking for.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Submitting the Form
It's a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to store and pass down from the SubmitContextProvider context provider component, but if you simply just want a button rendered in ComponentB to submit the form element rendered by ComponentA then there is no need for using a React context at all, it can be achieved via HTML attributes/JSX props alone.

Assign an id attribute to the form element in one component:
const ComponentA = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, register, control, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("onSubmit", { data });
  };

  return (
    <form
      id="component-a-form" // <-- form id
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    >
      ...
      <button type="submit">Submit from ComponentA</button>
    </form>
  );
};


Assign a form attribute to the button element to submit the form corresponding to that form id value:
const ComponentB = () => {
  const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    console.log("component B submitted");
  };

  return (
    <button
      form="component-a-form" // <-- form id to submit
      onClick={handleButtonClick}
      type="submit"
    >
      Submit from ComponentB
    </button>
  );
};



Passing a Submit Handler from Context
If you are wishing to define/store the submit callback/handler in SubmitContextProvider and pass it down then the issue is that you are not storing a function into the submitForm state, but rather passing a function that React is assuming is a lazy initializer function.
If you used React state like this then you need to pass a function that returns a function value to store.
Example:
const [submitForm, setSubmitForm] = useState(() => (data) => {
  console.log("Form submitted:", data);
});

This is to store the callback function value into the state.
That said, this is a very abnormal thing to do. If you are just passing a callback down then just declare it as such. You can use the useCallback hook to memoize and provide a stable reference (exactly what the state is, but more correct).
import { useCallback } from 'react';

const SubmitContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const submitForm = useCallback((data) => {
    console.log("Form submitted:", data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SubmitContext.Provider value={submitForm}>
      {children}
    </SubmitContext.Provider>
  );
};

